# get common value from structure and array

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I am trying to get common items from the arrays and structure . These given below array and structure:

```
MainAblbumArray =  ["1", "", "3", "7", "10", "4", "5", "6", "9", "12", "16", "11", "13", "14", "15"]

MainFavOrNotArray =  ["1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]

listStruct =  [Element(albmId: "1", favOrnot: "1"),
Element(albmId: "2", favOrnot: "0"),
Element(albmId: "3", favOrnot: "0"),
Element(albmId: "7", favOrnot: "0"),
Element(albmId: "10", favOrnot: "0"),
Element(albmId: "4", favOrnot: "0"),
Element(albmId: "5", favOrnot: "0"),
Element(albmId: "6", favOrnot: "1"),
Element(albmId: "9", favOrnot: "0"),
Element(albmId: "12", favOrnot: "0"),
Element(albmId: "16", favOrnot: "0"),
Element(albmId: "11", favOrnot: "0"),
Element(albmId: "13", favOrnot: "0"),
Element(albmId: "14", favOrnot: "0"),
Element(albmId: "15", favOrnot: "0")]
```

**Question**:  When i move forward to next screen in which required albumid or favornot value . so i got the favorNot  id from MainFavOrNotArray(Array) and albumid from MainAblbumArray(Array) but i really confused how to match value favornot from listStruct(structure).

When i trying to llistStruct.filter { $0.favOrnot == "1" } give me error give me below please check screen shot:

1.[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBEzJ.png)

2.[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lohNc.png)

Can someone please explain to me how to solve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you applying a filter by albumid or favOrNot values?

Comment: Unsure if I am the only one who finds your question is unclear. Could you refine it?

Comment: Is this what you want `listStruct.filter { $0.favOrnot == "1" }` ?

Comment: yes but give me error please check my update question

Comment: yes @RajeshKumarR applying filter but give me error please check latest updated question

Comment: Why do you keep MainAblbumArray and MainFavOrNotArray? You don't need both of these arrays

Comment: okay but if i want Element(albmId: "10", favOrnot: "0"), how to get these value, i really confused. @RajeshKumarR

Comment: check my answer for searching an album with id "10"

Answer (score 1):

Change your Element struck like this

```
struct Element {
    var albmId: String
    var favOrnot: Bool
}
```

And delete `MainAblbumArray`, `MainFavOrNotArray` arrays

When you want to get all favourite albums use filter like this

```
let favList = listStruct.filter { element -> Bool in
   return element.favOrnot
}
```

in short

```
let favList = listStruct.filter { $0.favOrnot }
```

**Search Album from array**

```
let albumIdToSearch = "10"
let album = listStruct.first(where: { element -> Bool in
  return element.albmId == albumIdToSearch
})
```